# Find a sequence of functions s.t. $\lim_{x \to 0} (\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x)) \ne \lim_{n \to \infty} (\lim_{x \to 0} f_n(x))$

Tags: real-analysis

Find a sequence of continuous functions $f_n : \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ such that $\lim_{x \to 0} (\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x))$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} (\lim_{x \to 0} f_n(x))$ exist and are unequal.

**My Attempt:** The function $f_n(x) = \frac {nx} {nx+1}$ has these properties.

We have that, 
$$\begin{aligned}
\lim_{n \to \infty} (\lim_{x \to 0} f_n(x)) &= \lim_{n \to \infty} \left ( \lim_{x \to 0} \frac {nx} {nx+1}\right)\\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty} \left ( 0 \right) \\
& = 0 ,
\end{aligned}$$

$$\begin{aligned}
\lim_{x \to 0} (\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x)) &= \lim_{x \to x} \left ( \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac {nx} {nx+1}\right)\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0} \left ( \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac {1} {1+1/nx}\right)\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0} 1 \\
& = 1.
\end{aligned}$$

However, this is not continuous. Is there a way I can salvage what I have done or is there no way to make this continuous? I was thinking about trying to make the discontinuity removable and then using a piecewise extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first thought was to try with 
$$
\frac{n^2x^2}{n^2x^2+1}.
$$

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you.

Comment: Glad I could help.